# Reshape long data.frame into a wide structure using plyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

```
> A <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(1,2,1,2), v = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4))
> A
  x y   v
1 1 1 0.1
2 1 2 0.2
3 2 1 0.3
4 2 2 0.4

> B <- dcast(A, x~y)
Using v as value column: use value.var to override.
> B
  x   1   2
1 1 0.1 0.2
2 2 0.3 0.4
```

Is it possible to reshape A into B **using plyr** and if yes how would it be done?

Comment: We expect you to do a little more research on your own first.  You posted 2 questions back-to-back that are identical except one asks for the solution to use plyr and the other data.table.  In the other question, you make it clear you have not familiarized yourself with data.table yet, and in the comments of the answer to this question you make it clear that you are not familiar with plyr.  If it's important to you that the solution is a plyr solution, then it is a pre-requisite that you first attempt to learn what plyr is/does.

Comment: I am curious about this use case. Don't see why being interested in two separate solutions is a problem.

Comment: @Яaffael1984 The problem is you don't show any effort to resolve the problem in your own. Imagine I ask post this as a question and I ask you how can I do this in `php` without any attempt?

Comment: that is a bit harsh. I just like non-trivial use cases that are of acute practical relevance to get an idea on how something works. It's like some people read magazines from back to front. Just a matter of personal preferences ;)

Comment: BTW - I did go through the manual for plyr. I just didn't find what I was looking for and the answer by agstudy shows that the solution is certainly non-trivial. So I don't know why this negative feedback and the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes for example you can do this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(A,.(x),function(t)setNames(t$v,t$y))
  x   1   2
1 1 0.1 0.2
2 2 0.3 0.4
```

*EDIT* add Some explanations about the use of `ddply` (better to read the documentation and see the many examples here in SO or in the net):

The general syntax is the following:

```
ddply(data.frame, variable(s), function, optional arguments)
```

- data.frame = A
- variable = `.(x)` : I use `.`. It is a plyr function. This function is
  used to capture the name of variables, not their current value.
- function =  anonymous function here `function(t){....}`. One liner function don't need `{`.

Within `ddply` , What I usually do is the following :

```
ddply(mydf, .(var), function(t) browser() )
```

Then I inspect t in real time ...

Comment: I would appreciate few more clarifications as I am new to plyr. F.x.: what does '.(X)' express - does this dot have a special meaning? Why does it just use function(t) - is that a regular anonymous function? I am wondering because the body is missing. :)